# Watch file(s) for modifications algorithm

Tags: language-agnostic, operating-system, filesystems

I was simply wondering how file watching algorithms are implemented. For instance, let's say I want to apply a filter (i.e., search/replace a string) to a file every time it is modified, what technique should I use? Obviously, I could run an infinite loop that would check every file in a directory for modifications, but it might not be very efficient. Is there any way to get notified directly by the OS instead? For the sake of demonstration, let's assume a *nix OS and whatever language (C/Ruby/Python/Java/etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux has [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), and judging from the wikipedia links, Windows has something similar called 'Directory Management'. Without something like inotify, you can only poll..

Answer (score 2):

In Linux there is the [Inotify](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Inotify) subsystem which will alert you to file modification.

Answer (score 1):

JavaSE 7 will have [File Change Notification](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/#6) as part of NIO.2 updates.

Answer (score 1):

There are wrappers to inotify that make it easy to use from high-level languages. For example, in ruby you can do the following with [rb-inotify](http://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify):

```
notifier = INotify::Notifier.new

# tell it what to watch
notifier.watch("path/to/foo.txt", :modify) {puts "foo.txt was modified!"}
notifier.watch("path/to/bar", :moved_to, :create) do |event|
  puts "#{event.name} is now in path/to/bar!"
end
```

There's also [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) but I was unable to come up with an example as concise as the above.